# Bash filename tab completion

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete, tab-completion, globbing

I have noticed sometimes that tab completion is helpfully filtered in bash. I am a java programmer and often use the `java` and `javac` commands in the terminal for quick or remote tasks.

Say I have the two usual files in a directory: `MyProgram.java` and `MyProgram.class`

If I ask bash to tabcomplete from the command prefix `java M`, it fills straight out to `java MyProgram`, this is helpful. Clearly either bash is configured to only accept ***.class** completions for the `java` command (and knows to strip the file extension), or the `java` command is telling bash this somehow.

I would like to accomplish the same with a text editor, so I could type in `nano M` and have it tab complete to `nano MyProgram.java` rather than pausing at `nano MyProgram.`, is it possible to say, blacklist ***.class** from nano's tab complete?

Most of all I'd just be interested to know if this is a bash configuration or something program-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java` has a separate auto-completion script that overrides the default completion mechanism. On my distribution (Arch Linux), it is installed in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/java`.

To override the behaviour of tab-completion, you could create such a script. If you just want to have all `.class` files ignored for every command, you could set the `FIGNORE` variable (e.g. in your `~/.bashrc`). Example: `FIGNORE=.class`. From the manual page of `bash`:

> FIGNORE
>   A  colon-separated  list  of  suffixes to ignore when performing filename completion (see READLINE below).  A filename whose suffix matches one of the entries in FIGNORE is excluded from the list of matched filenames.  A sample value is ".o:~".